# Slideshow counter not resetting for multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a simple slideshow type application which is in multiple parts of my page.  Each slide show has an array which holds specific information for each slide show.  The issue I'm having is, when I use one slide show and cycle through to the last element in the array then go to another slide show, I need to click multiple times to get the new array to begin cycling.  I know the issue is that the counter variable I have created is not resetting but I'm not sure why or how to fix it.  Can anyone provide a solution?

**HTML**

```
<section id="games" class="page">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="screen"></div>
        <div class="desc">
            <p>Solar System Sim is a 3D simulation of our galaxy built in Unity and written in C#. Clicking on each planet in the simulation will zoom and center on the planet, while clicking on the sun will return the camera to its original position.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="control left"></span>
            <span class="control right"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="webApps" class="page">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="screen"></div>
        <div class="desc">
            <p>Word Count</p>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="control left"></span>
            <span class="control right"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
var counter = 0;
var screen = document.getElementsByClassName("screen");
var control = document.getElementsByClassName("control");
for(var i = 0; i < control.length; i++){
    control[i].onclick = function(){
        var leftArrowClicked = this.classList.contains("left");
        var rightArrowClicked = this.classList.contains("right");
        SlideShowControls = function(){
            if(leftArrowClicked){
                counter--;
            }
            if(rightArrowClicked){
                counter++;
            }
            SlideShow = function(slides, whichSlideShow){
                var desc = document.getElementsByClassName("desc")[whichSlideShow].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
                if(counter < 0){
                    counter = slides.length - 1;
                }
                if(counter > slides.length - 1){
                    counter = 0;
                }
                desc.textContent = slides[counter][0];
                screen[whichSlideShow].style.backgroundImage = "url(" +slides[counter][1] +")";
            }
            if(CurrentPage.page == "games"){
                SlideShow(games, 0);
            }
            if(CurrentPage.page == "webApps"){
                SlideShow(webApps, 1);
            }
            console.log(counter);
        }
        SlideShowControls();
    }
}
```

Comment: may put var counter=0; into the first line of the SlideShow function?

Comment: @Jonasw The SlideShow function or SlideShowControls function?

Comment: well, i think i should better suggest you to rewrite your whole code, see my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to bind your slide shows onto each arrow pair so that they dont affect each other:

```
function SlideShow(slides,descid, left, right){
//to prevent bugs:
if(!(slides&&descid!==undefined&&left&&right)){console.error("missing args");return;}

//the magic unique counter
var counter=0;

//the event handlers:
left.onclick=function(){counter--;update()};
right.onclick=function(){counter++;update();};

//the function to redraw the slide
function update(){
var desc = document.getElementsByClassName("desc")[descid].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
  if(counter < 0){
    counter = slides.length - 1;
  }
  if(counter > slides.length - 1){
    counter = 0;
  }
  desc.textContent = slides[counter][0];
  screen[descid].style.backgroundImage = "url(" +slides[counter][1] +")";
}

//draw the slide the first time
update();
}
```

Use like this:

```
var arrow=document.getElementsByClassName("control");
SlideShow(games,0,arrow[0],arrow[1]);
SlideShow(webApps,1,arrow[2],arrow[3]);
```

The main problem is that counter just exists once, while you have multiple slides. Ive put counter into the slideShow function, so it is bound via Closures to the event listeners. Ive also restructured your code, its a replacement of yours

Comment: default value in function is not yet standarised !

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this, it works exactly the way I want it to.  I was trying to do it with closures(Or how I thought I understood them) but wasn't exactly sure how to do it and was most definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: @Robert glad to help ;). the cool thing about closures in js is that you dont need to think much about it. You will reach the point that you just write code, that simply works...

Comment: @Jonasw yeah, I guess I need to start keeping up to date with the new stuff.  Too set in the old ways of JS.

Answer (score 0):

Inside this code:

```
if(leftArrowClicked){
    counter--;
}
if(rightArrowClicked){
    counter++;
}
```

You should take into account when you reach 0 or n, being ne the number of slides, otherwise, you can get negative or saturated values and when the arrows are clicked nothing will moveuntil you reach a valid value

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I've just tested in on jsfiddle and it works perfect https://jsfiddle.net/whnzwzuq/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood the question. You should put a little bit of effort explaining things better. One easy solution is to have an array with different counters

Answer (score 0):

1 - I suggest you to avoid any problems, you have to encapsulate your code in a function and called it.

2 - check this

```
            if(leftArrowClicked && counter != 0){
                counter--;
            }
            if(rightArrowClicked && counter <= slides.length){
                counter++;
            }
```

I hope this helped you

Comment: 1. Yep, but either get more specific, or its rather a comment. 2. The user implemented a different behaviour already (infinite slides)